# Disable vulnerable cipher suites

Tags: tls, vulnerability, ciphers

As a part of my learning, I installed OpenVAS into one of our Ubuntu test servers and scan the said server. I have the results and I wanted to remediate the findings as part of my learning the Linux system.

I solve some of it but I'm stuck with this vulnerability:
SSL/TLS: Report Vulnerable Cipher Suites for HTTPS

```
'Vulnerable' cipher suites accepted by this service via the TLSv1.0
protocol: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
 
'Vulnerable' cipher suites accepted by this service via the TLSv1.1
protocol: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
 
'Vulnerable' cipher suites accepted by this service via the TLSv1.2
protocol: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
```

I modified my `sshd_config` based on this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/951775/disable-weak-cipher-ubuntu-16). Using the same values provided.

I also modified my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` with these values I got from [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1  
SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256  
SSLHonorCipherOrder on  
SSLCompression      off  
SSLSessionTickets   off
```

This is also the value of my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf`

After a re-scan the vulnerability is still detected.
How can I remediate this? A step-by-step would be helpful.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @postoronnim Yes I did. Are my steps for remediation correct?

Comment: There might be a syntax issue. This question might help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409194/apache-httpd-specify-ciphersuite

Comment: 1. SSH has nothing to do with TLS. 2. Are you sure your scanner is connecting to apache and not something else? Software or device in front of apache, or a different port, for example for email? 3. Look into apache's error log, increase logging verbosity so it would output more details into the log. See that it reads and understands your configuration correctly, see what it thinks of negotiating with the scanner's TLS client.